# Deep linking broken after clicking the "Open in Safari" button

Tags: ios, ios9, deep-linking

I just implemented iOS9 deep linking in my app and it was working just fine. Then I figured out that there is a "Open in Safari" button on the top right corner of the screen (opposite to the "Back to [App]" button).

I clicked it and now my links will always open directly in Safari instead of going into my app.

Can anybody else reproduce that? Is there a way to undo that? I searched inside Settings but can't find any appropriate options.

Answer (score 5):

I found it. Just long-press the link and you will get the option to open it in your app again!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I found the answer myself :) And I guess it answers it, doesn't it? So once you hit the "Open in Safari" iOS will always open links for that domain in Safari. To change that again, just long press the link wherever you find it and tap "Open in [App]" again...